# Docker service failed to start application container engine on CentOS7

Tags: docker, centos7

Running service docker start presents:

```
Job for docker.service failed.  See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Both of those yield this error:

```
Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I do not have internet access on this machine, and all the similar issues were resolved with a "*yum reinstall docker*" or "*yum install device-mapper-event-libs*" or "*yum install docker-selinux*".  I've tried commenting out selinux under docker options but nothing changes.

What can I do?  Should I download docker-selinux for my architecture and transfer it over and manually install?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Adding some information, this is CentOS 7 Atomic Host & Docker version 1.71

Comment: Why can't you turn off selinux?

Comment: Turns out a line in my docker config was misspelled and it took me much longer than I care to admit to find it, but after I removed a renegade 'e' from registry, everything is working -_-

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to create a conf file, /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/hosts.conf with extra options but still didn't work. Finally, a reboot started docker service without any issues. 
Hope this helps someone.